# SQL statement select most recent date and group per id

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the most recent 'topic 1 value' for each detailsID for the most recent date per detailsID.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
SELECT detailsID,`Topic 1 Scores`, MAX(Date) 
FROM Information.scores 
WHERE `Topic 1 Scores` IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY `detailsID`,`Topic 1 Scores`
```

Is printing;

detailsID, Topic 1 Scores, MAX(Date)

2   0   26/09/2017

2   45  26/09/2017

2   100 26/09/2017

3   30  25/09/2017

3   80  14/10/2017

Rather than actually selecting the most recent date per detailsID?

Comment: You can't have a `WHERE` clause after `ORDER BY`.

Comment: How do you choose topic 70, both rows for detailid 1 have same date

Comment: I can't see any difference between this question and the duplicate I selected.

Comment: Show your attempt at using one of the solutions there, and if it doesn't work we can reopen and show you how to do it correctly.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, please can you view my ammendments?

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY \`detailsID\`,\`Topic 1 Scores\``

Comment: But that's not one of the solutions in the question I linked to. That will get the most recent date, it doesn't get the most recent score.

Comment: Hmmm @Barmar it is not selecting the most recent date..

Comment: I will keep trying

Answer (score 0):

A solution like this can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/1491895) in the linked question.

```
SELECT t1.detailsID, t1.`Topic 1 Scores`
FROM Information.scores AS t1
JOIN (SELECT detailsID, MAX(date) AS maxDate
      FROM Information.scores
      GROUP BY detailsID) AS t2 
ON t1.detailsID = t2.detailsID AND t1.date = t2.maxDate
```